# how to filter hierarchical_names having only n level of hierarchy from the list of hierarchical_names using lsearch and regexp

Tags: tcl

`hierarchy_names` = `a/b/c a x d/e f/g h/i/j/k l/m/n o/p`
I am trying to filter out `2 level` hierarchy_names ie `d/e` `f/g` and `o/p` from the list of hierarchy_names having multiple levels of hierarchy_names.

I tried `lsearch` but the problem is, it returns the matches having hierarchy level greater or equal to 2 ie `a/b/c` `d/e` `f/g` `h/i/j/k` `l/m/n` `o/p` but not exactly equals to 2 ie `d/e` `f/g` `o/p` due to its algorithm of returning element if it `contains` pattern.
I also tried `regexp` but the problem with it is, it returns 2 level hierarchy_names along with partial 2 level hierarchy present in higher level hierarchy_names ie `a/b` `d/e` `f/g` `h/I` `j/k` `l/m`

```
set hier {a/b/c a x d/e f/g h/i/j/k l/m/n}
puts [lsearch -all -inline -regexp $hier {\w+/\w+}]
puts [regexp -all -inline {\w+/\w+} $hier]
```

`d/e` `f/g` `o/p`

Comment: Usually if you want to use only regexp, you'll need lookarounds (both lookbehind and lookahead), but since Tcl's re engine does not support lookbehinds, it becomes more complex, though not impossible. For instance, you could use [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/CceVnD/1). When using -inline and -all, you'll get pairs of matches, the odd matches (i.e. at indexes 1, 3, 5, etc) are the strings you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry for the expression but _its not working_. The reason is, `lookarounds` are the `zero-length assertion` ie they are _not expected to return anything_. Those will just _mark the position_ and _try to match `main reg-expression` around that_.

Comment: The actual reason why it's not working is because the Tcl re flavour [doesn't allow captures in lookaheads](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M28), I didn't know about that until checking the manual. But there's a different method that can be used, namely something like [this](https://ideone.com/5yBXnV). I put it in an ide this time, so we clearly see the output of the code.

Comment: We can postprocess output of regexp indeed like `dict values [regexp -all -inline -- {(?:\s+|^)(\w+/\w+)(?=\s+|$)} $hier]` (referred by @mrcalvin), but just wanted to know if we can do it just using regexp. But thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Line anchors might help you in this case.

```
% lsearch -all -inline -regexp $hier {^\w+/\w+$}
d/e f/g
```

Comment: Ohhh..!! I tried with word boundary ie `\m \M` but it didn't work in both case. Now at least _lsearch_ is working. what about _regexp_?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a different tool in Tcl's arsenal (assuming you have Tcl 8.6).

```
set hierarchy_names {a/b/c a x d/e f/g h/i/j/k l/m/n o/p}
set filtered [lmap n $hierarchy_names {
    if {[llength [file split $n]] != 2} continue
    string cat $n
}]
puts $filtered
# d/e f/g o/p
```

This uses `lmap` to apply a short script to each element of the list. The result of the list is either a `continue` signal (which skips the element) or the element; the test is done by looking at the length of the output list of `file split`.

Comment: Thanks for your _out of the box_ answer :)...! I would also like to know _how it can be done using regexp_. While using _lsearch_, _line anchors_ can be used to force _match only if pattern covers the whole of a list element_, but incase of regexp, to match words, I used `\m\w+/\w+\M` but its not working because Tcl consider only `\w+` as one word and I want Tcl to consider `[\w/]+` as one word. So how to do that using regexp?

Comment: Hey @DonalFellows , can you help us out to do this using only single regexp?

Answer (score 1):

> what about regexp?

You may devise a regular expression like this:

```
 (?:\s+|^)(\w+/\w+)(?=\s+|$)
```

- The first non-capturing group anchors the match pattern at the beginning of the string or a list element.
- The second capturing group actually stores what you are after.
- The positive lookahead makes sure that the match pattern does not become too greedy (i.e., flows into the subsequent list element).

This will return an even list of matches, with a submatch at the odd positions. To filter them out, you may use `[dict values]`, or an explicit `[foreach]`, e.g..

```
dict values [regexp -all -inline -- {(?:\s+|^)(\w+/\w+)(?=\s+|$)} $hier]
```

Comment: I am wondering whether someone wiser than me can optimise the regex in a way that the submatches (the intended matches with a whitespace prefix) are not reported? So the final filtering would not be needed any longer?